# A Strange Growth has Sprouted in the Center Stalks of my Dracaena

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, growth, dracaena

[image]I have had a Dracaena for 5 years. It just recently sprouted a bud like growth in the center of several of its stalks. What is this and what does it mean?

Comment: Welcome. Can you share some photos?

Comment: Seems your plant is flowering. Congratulations

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Same plant developed a fungus prior to budding. I cut off six of the leaves affected. In the last three days four or more leaves have lighter colored spots. I’m assuming this is the same fungus. I’m afraid to put it in shock, but should I just cut back all affected leaves?? Thanks for the help...

Comment: Please add this information to the question by editing. It will go on top of the active questions and be seen by more people.